# SOA Suite - How to automatically enable Web Service Rest support after composite deploy

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soa, soa-suite

I have a composite with a SOAP web service entry point running on SOA Suite. We will have a new client for that web service, but this client cannot speak SOAP, so we will have to publish that entry point on a REST endpoint. I know I can enable REST Support to the existing web service through EM console, but I would like to have this configuration enabled by default after deploy.

My research for ways to do that using a property or attribute on a configuration plan did not get useful informations.

Does anyone know how could I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST Support is formal part of SOA Suite 12c. Download and install that and then you can easily add a REST interface to a SOAP composite. Also, 12c now installs without RCU/DB, etc - just start the Integrated WLS domain in JDev and it builds itself and you are up and deploying in under 20 mins. And [this](http://javaoraclesoa.blogspot.com/2014/06/soa-suite-12c-introducing-rest-adapter.html) may help.